# get_user_by asking for string while string is given

Tags: users, errors

I've added an extra field to the login form. When trying to get the user's value of that field(before checking if it's equal) I have a `get_user_by('login', $username);`. $username being an email adres(the only thing I'll allow.)

The specific error is:
`Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /(removed for privacy)/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php on line 201`

Full code: (After click on login on /wp-login)

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'filter_login_auth', 10, 3);
function filter_login_auth($username, $password) {
    //get posted value
    $value = $_POST['klantnr'];

    //get user object
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);

    //get stored klantnr
    $stored = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'klantnr',  true);

    if(!$user || empty($value) || $value != $stored) {
        //No user, empty, or not correct
        remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);

        //Create error to return
        $user = new WP_Error('denied', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: Je klantnummer is niet correct."));
    }

    // return null so if klantnr is correct the script continues.
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you assign the vlue to `$username` varible?

Comment: Has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code, you use the first argument passed to `wp_authenticate_user` filter callback. That is a WP_User object, it not a email address and it is not a string.

You may be confusing because of the name of the variable, `$username`, I suggest to change the name to `$user`, whcih is more appropiate and it is a better representation of the real value of that variable.

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'filter_login_auth', 10, 3);
function filter_login_auth( $user, $password ) {
    //get posted value
    $value = $_POST['klantnr'];

    //get user object
    $user = get_user_by('login', $user->user_login);

    // .....

}
```

But you don't need that because `get_user_by()` returns a user object and you already have it:

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'filter_login_auth', 10, 3);
function filter_login_auth( $user, $password ) {
    //get posted value
    $value = $_POST['klantnr'];

    // You don't need this, you already have the user object
    // get user object
    //$user = get_user_by('login', $user->user_login);

    // .....

}
```

For more information, see [`wp_authenticate_user` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/).

Comment: EDIT: didn't see your edit. going to try it out! I'll let you know

Comment: It works! //Marked as answer